# Overriding ResponseWriter interface to catch HTTP errors

Tags: go

I'm coding a web application in Go, and while various mux libraries provide a way to set a custom 404 error handler, there's nothing for other 4xx and 5xx error codes.

One suggestion is to override the WriteHeader method in the ResponseWriter interface and check the status code, but I'm confused as to how this would actually be written (the overriding of ResponseWriter methods, before outputting).  One possible example can be found from the [negroni package](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni/blob/c7477ad8e330bef55bf1ebe300cf8aa67c492d1b/negroni.go#L73).

Would this be the correct way to serve a custom template for 4xx and 5xx errors?  Could anyone provide an example of how this could be implemented?

## **Update**

Big thanks to David and elithrar for their responses and code.  The `Interceptor` struct that David coded can be used in a wrapper for the server mux, as elithrar shows in the comments.  For those looking for further explanation as to why and how this works, [this section from astaxie's book](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/03.3.html) gives some very good info on the workings of the net/http package, along with viewing the [server.go source code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go) from the net/http package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mux libraries only have a means of setting the not found handler as a means of giving you a way to intercept requests where the mux can't resolve the URL to it's known mappings.

For example, you do:

```
mux.Handle("/foo",fooFunc)
mux.Handle("/bar",barFunc)
```

But the client accesses `/baz` to which the mux has no mapping.

They do not actually intercept a 404 going to the client, they just invoke the not found handler when it runs in to this problem.

Also, if your /foo handler sends a 404 response, the not found does not get invoked.

If you want custom pages for various return responses from your mapped URLs, simply make the various handlers write the correct response.

If you don't control that logic (ie: the framwork is writing something and has no means to override), then you may want to intercept all requests and override the http.ResposeWriter with response code detection logic.

Here's an example interceptor that basically does what you want.  On [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/kKmMBDjMq8)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)
import "net/http"

type Interceptor struct {
    origWriter http.ResponseWriter
    overridden bool
}

func (i *Interceptor) WriteHeader(rc int) {
    switch rc {
    case 500:
        http.Error(i.origWriter, "Custom 500 message / content", 500)
    case 404:
        http.Error(i.origWriter, "Custom 404 message", 404)
    case 403:
        i.origWriter.WriteHeader(403)
        fmt.Fprintln(i.origWriter, "Custom 403 message")
    default:
        i.origWriter.WriteHeader(rc)
        return
    }
    // if the default case didn't execute (and return) we must have overridden the output
    i.overridden = true
    log.Println(i.overridden)
}

func (i *Interceptor) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if !i.overridden {
        return i.origWriter.Write(b)
    }

    // Return nothing if we've overriden the response.
    return 0, nil
}

func (i *Interceptor) Header() http.Header {
    return i.origWriter.Header()
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the example!

I think I see what you mean, where my handlers can write specific 4xx and 5xx errors for the routes according to the app logic, right?  My concern though would be the errors generated from the net/http package itself and just keeping everything consistent with a single error page.

Where exactly would I have `&Interceptor{origWriter: nil}` so I can replace nil with the actual `http.ResponseWriter`?  I'm thinking it would go in the `ServeHTTP` function for my own `http.Handler`, but not sure how this would look (or if that's correct).

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you show it being used in `main()` with a simple `http.Handle` call like

`http.Handle("/test", InterceptHandler)`

(if that's the right way)?

Comment: @eclipse1121 Wrap your entire mux with some middleware that replaces the default ResponseWriter with the InterceptWriter - http://play.golang.org/p/esiiY7p-CC

Comment: @elithrar thanks! I tried implementing it as you show with a slight change (no mux just an http.Handle) here, [http://play.golang.org/p/EtpAa7KYOn](http://play.golang.org/p/EtpAa7KYOn), but it doesn't seem to work when trying to catch a 404 error.  I'm starting to wonder, how is ServeHTTP implemented?  If the net/http package raises an error and never calls the ServeHTTP handlers for various routes when an error occurs, then is it impossible to catch them before they're written without essentially creating a custom server?  Also thank you for your blog, it's been helpful!

Comment: also in that code, the `/test` route loads but the 'Testing' text is never sent to the browser.

Comment: David's answer has a slight error: it doesn't write when `i.overridden` is false. It should be the other way around. See here: http://play.golang.org/p/kKmMBDjMq8 - if you want to avoid having to wrap every single handler, then create a `mux := http.NewServeMux()` and wrap that (only).

Comment: Ok cool I see the fix you did for the text not showing.  I also see how the `BadHandler` works, however this is still what I would consider an application generated error response vs Interceptor catching all error responses, outside of what's defined in my handlers.  For instance, browsing to `/bad` shows the `Custom 403 message` error, but browsing to `/notfound` shows the standard `404 page not found` instead of the `Custom 404 message` one.

Comment: Is it just impossible to catch errors created from outside of your own `ServeHTTP` handler?  My goal is to just have 100% coverage of all errors so a standard error page can be shown.  For example, outside of rewriting the net/http package, how would you catch [this error](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1430)?  The `timeoutHandler` struct in [server.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L2328) seems like a good example - they define a `ServeHTTP` function and that's what sends the 503 code if appropriate.  Should I only worry about 4xx and 5xx errors in my app logic then?

Comment: Also if that's the case, seems like the net/http package should offer some handler for all errors it can generate that can be written to the browser, so showing a custom error page becomes trivial.

Comment: You *can* catch 404 errors - like I said, if you wrap the entire `ServeMux` you can intercept anything. The problem with using the default mux (which is what the `nil` in ListenAndServe means) is that the 404 never hits your handlers in the first place, and you don't get to catch it. This will intercept 404's: http://play.golang.org/p/KZMBVCQ9MT

Comment: ... and here's an article I wrote on how to do this with custom handler types as well, so you can `return CustomErrorType` from your handlers and determine what to show/render: http://elithrar.github.io/article/http-handler-error-handling-revisited/

Comment: @elithrar awesome, thank you!  I tested and it works for the 404 error.  Was wondering if you could elaborate further?  Looking at the server.go source with what you pointed out about the default mux, can you tell me if I'm understanding this correctly?  Looks like the `http.Server` struct has a `http.Handler` embedded which defaults to `http.DefaultServeMux` if nil on creation (created via exported `ListenAndServe` function).  I'm thinking this code would only work then for errors written using the writer, i.e. [this](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1430) won't be intercepted?