# How do I get Response statusCode in golang middleware?

Tags: go

How do I get Response statusCode in golang middleware?

ResponseWriter have only WriteHeader interface, I can't find get interface.

Comment: You just have a method like returnWith etc. that you use instead of using middleware

Comment: so, it is can't get in golang middleware?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528330/overriding-responsewriter-interface-to-catch-http-errors, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162211/gorilla-mux-best-way-to-catch-response-codes and others.

Comment: I get, think you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gorilla mux, best way to 'catch' response codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162211/gorilla-mux-best-way-to-catch-response-codes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding ResponseWriter interface to catch HTTP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528330/overriding-responsewriter-interface-to-catch-http-errors)

Answer (score 15):

This method is feasible.

```
    type loggingResponseWriter struct {
        http.ResponseWriter
        statusCode int
    }

    func NewLoggingResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter) *loggingResponseWriter {
        return &loggingResponseWriter{w, http.StatusOK}
    }

    func (lrw *loggingResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
        lrw.statusCode = code
        lrw.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
    }

    func wrapHandlerWithLogging(wrappedHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            log.Printf("--> %s %s", req.Method, req.URL.Path)

            lrw := NewLoggingResponseWriter(w)
            wrappedHandler.ServeHTTP(lrw, req)

            statusCode := lrw.statusCode
            log.Printf("<-- %d %s", statusCode, http.StatusText(statusCode))
        })
    }
```

Comment: This method does have some issues though. It will break use of all the extra interfaces - Flusher, Pusher, CloseNotifier, and Hijacker.

Comment: Yes, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is the easiest/simplest method, just should be noted it breaks all the other interfaces. If those are needed as is status code logging, there are other options, like writing a `func WriteHeader(w http.ResponseWriter, status int)` that will call `w.WriteHeader(status)` and do the logging. But that requires making sure none of your code calls `w.WriteHeader` directly and uses the utility func instead. Have to weigh the pros/cons in each use case.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for weighing in. Could you please clarify what you mean by "it breaks all other interfaces"?

Comment: Yes - the `loggingResponseWriter` will not support `CloseNotifier`, `Flusher`, `Hijacker`, or `Pusher`, even if the original `ResponseWriter` did.

Comment: @Adrian I must be missing something. The loggingResponseWriter will satisfy the only needed interface which is ResponseWriter. Where are these other interfaces used? ServeHTTP specifies it only needs ResponseWriter.

Comment: @StevenEckhoff there are additional interfaces that a response writer *may* support (which I listed, and you can look up for more info), and handlers may use that functionality when it's available, and if they do, this method will not allow exercising that functionality under test.

Comment: @Adrian okay so I guess what everyone is left wondering about is how these interfaces are reached. The only way I can see this happening is through a type assertion down the ServeHTTP chain (i.e. `w.(http.Hijacker)`). Of course this will panic and you'll learn you have an issue fairly quickly. I was not aware that this is done. A solution to this would be to use the second form of type assertion to test whether a particular interface is supported and then make sure your wrapped type also supports it. This is a good idea for a robust library, but may be overkill for a one-off middleware.

Comment: Kubernetes has a nice utility function for configuring a writer while respecting all interfaces it may implement. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a9593d634c6a053848413e600dadbf974627515f/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/responsewriter/wrapper.go#L37-L96

Comment: As @Adrian mentioned, this is a well documented issue with Go optional interfaces. To avoid this problem it would require a non trivial implementation of the responseWriter wrapper. This library is minimalist that solves this exact problem: https://github.com/felixge/httpsnoop

Answer (score 9):

Use negroni. It works the same as @huangapple answer, but with the handler actually implementing all the interfaces.

```
import (
    "github.com/urfave/negroni"
)

func wrapHandlerWithLogging(wrappedHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("--> %s %s", req.Method, req.URL.Path)

        lrw := negroni.NewResponseWriter(w)
        wrappedHandler.ServeHTTP(lrw, req)

        statusCode := lrw.Status()
        log.Printf("<-- %d %s", statusCode, http.StatusText(statusCode))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Long story short, you should wrap http.ResponseWriter by yourself or using libraries. If you want to implement it by yourself you can find some hints from [Negroni](https://github.com/urfave/negroni/blob/master/response_writer.go) source code

Answer (score 1):

in my case, where I don't use an external library, and I don't want to wrap `http.ResponseWriter`. I have to add the response's status in the request's context for later use in logging. So I create a small helper to write a status in both ResponseWriter and the request's context at the same time.

```
type AppContext string
var StatusCode = AppContext("statuCode")

func WriteHeaderAndContext(w http.ResponseWriter, statusCode int, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), StatusCode, statusCode)
    *r = *(r.WithContext(ctx))

    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}
```

in the logging, I retrieve the value as

```golang
r.Context().Value(StatusCode)
```

The downside happens on the called side, where it is a little unusual to look. e.g

```golang
WriteHeaderAndContext(w, http.StatusCreated, r)
```

where we normally do

```golang
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used @huangapple answer but i created a little library that gives some info of the setup .etc

https://github.com/joegasewicz/status-writer