# Accessing updated Request in wrapped middleware

Tags: go, http

I'm trying to write a logging middleware for a simple http server. I want to log the response status and bytes written.

To accomplish this, I followed [How do I get Response statusCode in golang middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272536/how-do-i-get-response-statuscode-in-golang-middleware) to wrap the ResponseWriter like so:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/urfave/negroni"
)

func wrapHandlerWithLogging(wrappedHandler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("--> %s %s", req.Method, req.URL.Path)

        lrw := negroni.NewResponseWriter(w)
        wrappedHandler.ServeHTTP(lrw, req)

        statusCode := lrw.Status()
        log.Printf("<-- %d %s", statusCode, http.StatusText(statusCode))
    })
}
```

Now the problem is I'd also like to log some context variables set by middleware that come after logger in the chain. They're set on r.Context() but since the r here is the older request before the auth middleware added extra info, I have no way of accessing them.

```golang
email, ok := r.Context().Value(someContextKey).(string) // ok always false, as middleware setting key runs after logger
```

Is there a way to access the updated request object here? Running logger after the auth middleware isn't an option, as they return early for failed auth requests.

Comment: There is no way to access context variables added to contexts derived from the request context by using just the request context itself. There may be many contexts derived from the request context.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there _any_ way to accomplish what I'm going for here? Writing a logging middleware that can access context variables?

Comment: Put a logging structure that will be filled in by the handler into the context, and use that on return from the handler.

Comment: I don't understand. This logging structure will do the logging? Or will it encapsulate my context variables? And I use that on return from which handler?

Comment: For instance, you can have `type LogInfo struct { ID string }`, and then pass a context that has `&logInfo` to the handler. The handler sets `logInfo.ID`, and then in the middleware you log `logInfo`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600825/accessing-updated-request-in-wrapped-middleware#comment136806661_77600825) recommended, if you put a pointer in `context.Context` at the start of a request, downstream processing can update it.

Here's an example loosely mirroring your ask, with some recommendations at the end:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

// Details here: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.4:src/context/context.go;l=140-147
type key int

var logInfoKey key

// You'd likely want this struct + context functions in a separate package
// to avoid later import cycles
type LogInfo struct {
    Auth   *Auth
    Method string
    Path   string
}

type Auth struct {
    Foo string
}

func NewContext(ctx context.Context, info *LogInfo) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(ctx, logInfoKey, info)
}

func FromContext(ctx context.Context) (*LogInfo, bool) {
    u, ok := ctx.Value(logInfoKey).(*LogInfo)
    return u, ok
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    li := &LogInfo{Method: "GET", Path: "/"}
    log.Printf("--> %s %s", li.Method, li.Path)

    ctx = NewContext(ctx, li)
    downstream(ctx)

    log.Printf("--> Auth: %s", li.Auth.Foo)
}

func downstream(ctx context.Context) {
    li, ok := FromContext(ctx)
    if ok {
        li.Auth = &Auth{Foo: "bar"}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does introduce some "code smell".

Having downstream code paths propagate information back upstream like this can be surprising. To get around this, I'd suggest propagating a logger in context — instead of `*LogInfo` — that supports adding fields.

I'm most familiar with `zap`, but other loggers can do this such as `slog`. The calling code might look something like...

```golang
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Assuming you have a 'logging' package that either returns the current
    // logger or creates and returns a new one
    log := logging.FromContext(ctx)
    log = log.With(
        zap.String("method", "GET"),
        zap.String("path", "/"),
    )
    log.Info("received request")

    ctx = logging.NewContext(ctx, log)
    downstream(ctx)
}

func downstream(ctx context.Context) {
    // No need for conditional checking in downstream callers - if the logger
    // was never set upstream we'll get a fresh one here
    log := logging.FromContext(ctx)
    log = log.With(zap.String("auth_name", "foo"))
    log.Info("user logged in")
}
```